# Differential equation to Ito equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a differential equation:
$$\frac{dX}{dt}=f(X)+\epsilon X n(t)$$
where $f$ is a deterministic function, $\epsilon$ is a constant, $n(t)$ is a white Gaussian noise and $X$ is a random process.

I want to transfer it to an Ito form:
$$dX=g(X)dt+\epsilon XdW_t$$
where 
$W_t$ is a Weiner process.

I know that the Stratonovich form is
$$dX=f(X)dt+\epsilon XdW_t~.$$
How can I find $g(X)~$?

I found in a textbook that it equal to 
$$f(X)+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2 X~.$$

But I do not know if it is right, or any justification for that result.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This follows immediately from Ito's formula and the fact that
$$ \int X \circ dY= \int X dY+ \langle X,Y\rangle$$
for continuous semi-martingales $X,Y$. Here $\circ dY$ denotes the Stratonovich integral with respect to $Y$, and $dY$ without the $\circ$ denotes the Ito integral with respect to $Y$.

Comment: I cannot understand how it follows from Ito's formula.
Ito's formula represents the differential of a function of a random process.
Here it looks like the following needs to hold:
$dW=n(t)dt-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon dt$

Comment: Also what the brackets stand for?